# Verifying that a capital letter is at beginning of variable input in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, scripting, conditional-statements

I'm new to bash and need a little help with verifying that a name is capitalized at the beginning of a variable input. Here's what i'd like to achieve

```
#asks for new user information
read -p 'Username: ' var
    while [ first letter is capitalized ] 
    do go to next variable input
    else loop back and ask for input again
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use pattern matching:

```
while read -p 'Username: ' var && [[ $var != [[:upper:]]* ]]; do
    printf 'Please enter a capitalized name\n' >&2
done
```

Comment: So this throws me in a loop where it doesn't accept any input at all and doesn't move to the next variable input... Just prints 'Please enter a capitalized name.'

Comment: Sounds like standard input was redirected from somewhere else.

Comment: I'm an idiot, if forgot the `:` after `upper`. Thanks for your help. That worked.